# How can I revise this function to return stable data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, twitter, angularjs-directive

I'm using a directive to return return Tweets from a service that calls the Twitter API. But before I attach the Tweets to scope, I want to run some functions that will format the data to my liking. These things include reformatting the date, processing the text to HTML using entities, getting sentiment, etc.

```
/* Lazy loading */
        element.find('.scroll').scroll(function() {
            if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight()) {
                loadTweets(attrs.query,scope.maxId);
            }
        });

        /* Load tweets function */
        function loadTweets(query, maxId, sinceId) {

            /* Get tweets from service that calls API */
            gettweets(query, maxId, sinceId).then(function(tweets) {

                /* Set Max ID and Since ID for Paging */
                scope.maxId = tweets[tweets.length-1].id;
                scope.sinceId = tweets[0].id;

                /* Loop through response */
                for (var i in tweets) {

                    /* Return reply meta if reply */
                    if (tweets[i].in_reply_to_status_id_str) {
                        (function(j) {
                            gettweet(tweets[i].in_reply_to_status_id_str).then(function(tweet) {
                                tweets[j].reply = tweet;
                            });
                        })(i);
                    }

                    /* Return parsed date for moment filter */
                    tweets[i].created_at_parsed = new Date(Date.parse(tweets[i].created_at));

                    /* Return tweet html with entities */
                    tweets[i].text_linkified = linkify(tweets[i]);

                    /* Return sentiment from Mashape API */
                    (function(j) {
                        getsentiment(tweets[i].text).then(function(response) {
                            tweets[j].sentiment = response;
                        });
                    })(i);

                    /* Push Tweets into scope  */
                    scope.tweets.push(tweets[i]);
                }
            });
        }
```

This "almost" works, except when I'm paging through the data, sometimes the max_id doesn't get updated and I end up with duplicate Tweets.

How can I format this better to ensure my max_id updated only when all Tweets are returned successfully and the new tweets won't load until the max_id is up to date?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for (var i=0; i<tweets.length; i++)` ? (it's an array, not an object you're looping on isn't it ?)

Comment: I am looping on an object. This returns the same result.

Comment: If `tweets` is an object, how can you rely on `tweets.length` for `scope.maxId = tweets[tweets.length-1].id;` ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your code but I do now you should calculate the max_id as the id of the last tweet you have received in your last call *minus 1*. As for the rest of the questions on your post, or @topheman concern, as I say I don't really understand your code. Hope it helps.